# How to combine 2 child elements with identical name into single property using XmlSerializer class objects is C#

Tags: c#, linq, xmlserializer, xmlelement

I'm working on reading XML files data, problem is that I've would like to combine this:

```
- <FIELD>
   <FIELD-TYPE>9999</FIELD-TYPE> 
   <FIELD-TEXT>Cash 538,64</FIELD-TEXT> 
  </FIELD>
- <FIELD>
   <FIELD-TYPE>119</FIELD-TYPE> 
   <FIELD-AMOUNT>538.64</FIELD-AMOUNT> 
  </FIELD>
```

In single object property like this:

```
[XmlElement("FIELD-TEXT")]
    public string FieldText { get; set; }

[XmlElement("FIELD-AMOUNT")]
    public string FieldAmount { get; set; }
```

Currently I can read each parent element separately, which gives me this:
[image: ![enter image description here]

Is it possible to somehow configure XmlSerializer or objects?
I've also thought about adding another property that somehow combine these property using LINQ.

Expected out would need to look like this:
[image]

Haven't tried anything with XmlSerializer object configuration as I'm new to this and don't know where to start.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what is expected and what you tried

Comment: The xml is generated *broadly* similar to the object structure; if you want a significantly different xml output: you will need a different xml structure. So no: you can't readily make it generate multiple levels of xml from one object

Comment: @KrishnaMuppalla I've updated my question with output image of what the object data should look like.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps to contact two fields

```
var list1 =  doc.Descendants("FIELD-TEXT").Concat(doc.Descendants("FIELD-AMOUNT")).InDocumentOrder();            

foreach (var item in list1)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```